# TypeError build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id' in django

Tags: django, typeerror

In general, what can cause a build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id' error?

In particular after a migration of my project from one server to another I face this error.All templates rendered well apart from one.
I do not know where to search in order to fix it. Could it be an error raised from the template?

My view

```
@method_decorator(user_access_to_log, name='dispatch')
class StatisticsView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView, FormMixin):
    model = RequestRequest
    login_url = '/login/'
    template_name = 'statistics.html'
    form_class = DateMonthForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StatisticsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #logins = AuditEntry.objects.exclude(username='neuro')
        count = AuditEntry.objects.filter(action='user_logged_in').exclude(username='demo').exclude(username='neuro').values('username').annotate(total=Count('username')).order_by('total')

        #print(count)
        usernames = []
        counts = []
        for c in count:
            usernames.append(c['username'].encode('ascii','ignore'))
            counts.append(c['total'])
        print(usernames)
        requests = RequestRequest.objects.filter(referer__icontains='/shops/rest_new/',response=200,path='/rest/pharmakeia/').exclude(user=None).exclude(user__username='demo').exclude(user__username='neuro').values('user__username').annotate(total=Count('user__username')).order_by('total')
        print(requests)
        usernames_r = []
        counts_r = []
        for r in requests:
            usernames_r.append(r['user__username'].encode('ascii','ignore'))
            counts_r.append(r['total'])
        if self.request.POST:
            self.date_year = self.request.POST['date_year']
            self.date_month = self.request.POST['date_month']
        monthform = DateMonthForm(self.request.POST or None)
        context ['form'] = monthform
        context['counts_r'] = counts_r
        context['usernames_r'] = mark_safe(usernames_r)    
        context['counts'] = counts
        context['usernames'] = mark_safe(usernames)
        #context['logins'] = logins
        return context
```

widgets.py

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput, DateInput, DateTimeInput, TimeInput
import datetime
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.forms.widgets import Widget, Select
from django.utils.dates import MONTHS
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyEmailInput(TextInput):
    input_type = 'email'

class MyNumberInput(TextInput):
    input_type = 'number'

class MyTelephoneInput(TextInput):
    input_type = 'tel'

class MyDateInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
    format_key = 'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS'

class MyDateTimeInput(DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'datetime'

class MyTimeInput(TimeInput):
    input_type = 'time'


RE_DATE = re.compile(r'(\d{4})-(\d\d?)-(\d\d?)$')

class MonthYearWidget(Widget):
    """
    A Widget that splits date input into two <select> boxes for month and year,
    with 'day' defaulting to the first of the month.

    Based on SelectDateWidget, in 

    django/trunk/django/forms/extras/widgets.py


    """
    none_value = (0, '---')
    month_field = '%s_month'
    year_field = '%s_year'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, years=None, required=True):
        # years is an optional list/tuple of years to use in the "year" select box.
        self.attrs = attrs or {}
        self.required = required
        if years:
            self.years = years
        else:
            this_year = datetime.date.today().year
            self.years = range(this_year, this_year+3)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        try:
            year_val, month_val = value.year, value.month
        except AttributeError:
            year_val = month_val = None
            if isinstance(value, basestring):
                match = RE_DATE.match(value)
                if match:
                    year_val, month_val, day_val = [int(v) for v in match.groups()]

        output = []

        if 'id' in self.attrs:
            id_ = self.attrs['id']
        else:
            id_ = 'id_%s' % name

        month_choices = MONTHS.items()
        #if not (self.required and value):
        #    month_choices.append(self.none_value)
        month_choices.sort()
        local_attrs = self.build_attrs(id=self.month_field % id_)
        s = Select(choices=month_choices)
        select_html = s.render(self.month_field % name, month_val, local_attrs)
        output.append(select_html)

        year_choices = [(i, i) for i in self.years]
        #if not (self.required and value):
        #    year_choices.insert(0, self.none_value)
        local_attrs['id'] = self.year_field % id_
        s = Select(choices=year_choices)
        select_html = s.render(self.year_field % name, year_val, local_attrs)
        output.append(select_html)

        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))

    def id_for_label(self, id_):
        return '%s_month' % id_
    id_for_label = classmethod(id_for_label)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        y = data.get(self.year_field % name)
        m = data.get(self.month_field % name)
        if y == m == "0":
            return None
        if y and m:
            return datetime.date(int(y), int(m), 1).strftime( settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS[0] )
```

my traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: .../logging/

Django Version: 1.11.16
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'intranet',
 'bootstrap3',
 'registration',
 'crispy_forms',
 'fm',
 'dal',
 'dal_select2',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_filters',
 'django_crontab']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /var/www/vhosts/maps.karabinismedical.gr/geolocator/templates/base.html, error at line 0
   build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'   1 : {% load i18n %}
   2 : {% load static %}
   3 : {% load staticfiles %}
   4 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   5 : <html lang="en">
   6 :   <head>
   7 : 
   8 :     <meta charset="utf-8">
   9 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   10 :      <style>


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/library.py" in render
  203.         output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3/templatetags/bootstrap3.py" in bootstrap_form
  338.     return render_form(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3/forms.py" in render_form
  53.     return renderer_cls(form, **kwargs).render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3/renderers.py" in render
  87.         return mark_safe(self._render())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3/renderers.py" in _render
  230.         return self.render_errors(self.error_types) + self.render_fields()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3/renderers.py" in render_fields
  194.                 bound_css_class=self.bound_css_class,

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3/forms.py" in render_field
  69.     return renderer_cls(field, **kwargs).render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3/renderers.py" in render
  87.         return mark_safe(self._render())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3/renderers.py" in _render
  551.         html = self.field.as_widget(attrs=self.widget.attrs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in as_widget
  127.             **kwargs

File "/var/www/vhosts/maps.karabinismedical.gr/geolocator/intranet/widgets.py" in render
  77.         local_attrs = self.build_attrs(id=self.month_field % id_)

Exception Type: TypeError at /logging/
Exception Value: build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

Comment: You'd have to show the relevant template code as well.

Comment: @EndreBoth done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the fix-answer. In my widgets I had to change the code as below:

```
local_attrs=self.attrs
        local_attrs['id'] = self.year_field % id_
        s = Select(choices=month_choices)
        select_html = s.render(self.month_field % name, month_val, local_attrs)
        output.append(select_html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.11 introduced [template-based widget rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#template-based-widget-rendering). The `build_attrs` error can be caused by form widgets that need to be updated.

In your case, the traceback is showing you that the error is occuring in a widget on line 77 of `geolocator/intranet/widgets.py`.